# Jquery - Adding html before each new line in an array

Tags: jquery, html, split, append, newline

I've been working on trying to style the html CODE element by adding an ordered list on top of its content and then a a LI and a P before each new line, with their closing tags added to the end of each line.

This is what I have:

```
     $("#mydiv code").each(function(){
        var oldcontent = $(this).html();
        $(this).html("<span class='olnumbers'></span><ol class='code'>" + oldcontent + "</ol>");
        var lines = oldcontent.split(/[\n\r]/g);
        $.each(lines, function(e){
                $(this).html("<li><p>" + lines + "</p></li>");
        });

 });
```

This simply doesn't work. I get no errors, I don't know what is wrong.
Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: I should have mentioned: This works to the extent of adding the span and the OL outside of the content, but the LI and P are not added. 

However, if I put "alert(this)" inside of the each function, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use this within the each function.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

> jQuery.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) )
>
> collection The object or array to iterate over.
>
> callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) The function that will be
>   executed on every object.

Try this instead:

```
var html = [];
$.each(lines, function(i, val){
                html.push("<li><p>" + val + "</p></li>");
        });
$(this).html(html.join(''));
```

Comment: That works! But now my OL and span are not being appended - I think this is because of the "$(this).html(html.join(''));" line.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it - dumb mistake, the line I was using was replacing everything with the var oldcontent, so I made a new var and it works. Thanks!